# Laravel blade thinks I am trying to parse an object while controller outputs its a string

Tags: laravel

I have a MailController with the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mail\Contact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->json('name');
        $email = $request->json('email');
        $phone = $request->json('phone');
        $contact = $request->json('contact');
        $preference = $request->json('preference');
        $subject = $request->json('subject');
        $message = $request->json('message');

        Mail::to($request->json('email'))->send(new Contact($name, $email, $phone, $contact, $preference, $subject, $message));

        if (Mail::failures()) {
            return response(500);
        }

        return response(200);
    }
}
```

When I `var_dump()` the variable `$message` it says it is a string.

This is my Mail class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $name, string $email, string $phone, string $contact, string $preference, string $subject, string $message)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->contact = $contact;
        $this->preference = $preference;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subject)
            ->view('emails.contact')
            ->with([
                'name' => $this->name,
                'email' => $this->email,
                'phone' => $this->phone,
                'contact' => $this->contact,
                'preference' => $this->preference,
                'message' => $this->message,
                'subject' => $this->subject,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Where the same `var_dump()` also says it is a string.

And then I got my blade view here which says the `$message` variable is an object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body
    style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; color: #74787e; height: 100%; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-word-break: break-all; width: 100% !important; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; word-break: break-word;">
    <style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .inner-body {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            .footer {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .button {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
        style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                    style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="header"
                            style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
                            <a href="https://slenderyougemert.nl"
                                style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #3f51b5; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;">
                                {{config('app.name')}}
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- Email Body -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                            style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #edeff2; border-top: 1px solid #edeff2; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                            <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
                                <!-- Body content -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="content-cell"
                                        style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                                        <h1
                                            style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #2F3133; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">
                                            Ingevuld contactformulier door: {{$name}}</h1>
                                        <p

                                            style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787e; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">
                                            Het ingevulde contactformulier bevat de volgende data:
                                            <br />
                                            <br />
                                            E-mailadres: {{$email}}
                                            <br />
                                            Telefoonnummer: {{$phone}}
                                            <br />
                                            Graag contact opnemen via: {{$contact}}
                                            <br />
                                            Voorkeur dag en tijd: {{$preference}}
                                            <br />
                                            Betreft: {{$subject}}
                                            <br />
                                            Bericht: {{$message}}
                                            <br />
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

How is it even possible that it returns a string every time for every variable but for the `$message` variable it suddenly says it is an object? This should not be possible. Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variable from `message` to `msg` worked. Seems like this variable is preserved for something else. I will keep this question here if someone else needs it in the future.

Comment: "Laravel automatically makes the `$message` variable available to all of your email templates, so you don't need to worry about passing it in manually:" ... so yea, that name is already used